# Compare Index Numbers of Two Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to record the index value of these two objects so that I can then loop and do a comparison. At this point, I have the drop down lists able to return the index value and a separate script that will produce the index number upon changing the dropdown, but whenever I've tried to adjust that script and set a variable, I get an unidentified variable error. I've tried putting functions to recall it, but the unidentified variable still happens. Does anyone have any suggestions how can I record the index numbers of two arrays as variables?

```
<div id = box1>
<form>
 <select id ="bunny">
  <option value = "1">United States</option>
  <option value = "2">Canada</option>
  <option value = "3">France</option>
  <option value = "4">Hungary</option>
 </select>
</form> 
<br>
<form>
 <select id ="bunny2">
  <option value = "1">Washington, D.C.</option>
  <option value = "2">Ottawa</option>
  <option value = "3">Paris</option>
  <option value = "4">Budapest</option>  
 </select>  
</form>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('select').change(function(){
   alert($('option:selected',$(this)).index()); 
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: *How* did you "*adjust the script to set a variable*"?

Comment: Don't you just want to use `this.value` instead of that complex jQuery thingy?

Comment: Do u need solution where u can compare values of two select elements:bunny and bunny2?

Comment: Please show us the **code that isn't working**. Where is this: *"adjust that script and set a variable, I get an unidentified variable error"*?

Comment: If you want the index of the selected option, then `this.selectedIndex` will do, a value of -1 means no option is selected. Bergi has shown how to get the value.

Comment: I am trying to compare the values of the selected elements in bunny and bunny2. Initially, I had the jquery script copied underneath each form and this is how I tried to adjust the jquery script to save as a variable:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it dead simple, just keep track of the selects by yourself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var bunny = $('#bunny');
  var bunny2 = $('#bunny2');
  $('select').change(function() {
    alert(bunny.val() + ', ' + bunny2.val());
  });
</script>
```

Good enough?

Comment: I tried adjusting it into an if/else statement. However, the else statement is not getting read. I think it's because the $('select').change(function() is only checking the first condition.                                                                                            <script type="text/javascript">
    var bunny = $('#bunny');
    var bunny2 = $('#bunny2');
      $('select').change(function() {
       if (bunny = bunny2) {
          alert('Yes');
      }
       else  {
        alert('No');
     }
   });
 </script>

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is for comparrision. Also, you must compare the VALUES not the jquery-elements. So make that `if (bunny.val() == bunny2.val()) { alert("yes"); } else { alert('No'); }`